# Where is ESP8266 TCP/IP stack defined?

Tags: esp8266, reverse-engineering, networking

I just installed Micropython on my ESP8266 and realized that TCP/IP works fine with it. This made me realize I don't know where it's defined - options that came to my head are: 1) in Micropython code, 2) ESP8266 closed-source API, 3) the chip. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

The ESP8266 is a system-on-chip (SoC) WiFi solution. While a common setup is to have a dedicated microcontroller which talks to the ESP8266 with AT commands, it is in fact a fully functioning microcontroller which can be flashed with custom firmware.

The chip itself is physically made up of a Tensilica Xtensa core, a Winbond SPI flash, and a WiFi transceiver. These devices are all encased within the same physical package. The Xtensa architecture is a proprietary RISC architecture, but there is a toolchain available for it. There is a complete [Arduino core and framework port for the ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/cores/esp8266), which allows you to write your own Arduino code for the ESP8266 and have it running directly on the SoC, without the need for an external microcontroller. You can of course ignore the Arduino part and direclty compile your own native code using the Xtensa toolchain.

The firmware on the ESP8266 is *usually* what handles networking. If you look at the [ESP8266 Module Quick Start Guide](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf) you can see that the AT commands are used to manage IP addresses and create TCP/UDP packets. The actual networking stack is in the firmware. In this particular case it is part of the <strike>closed-source Expressif firmware.</strike> Expressif firmware, which has [an open-source SDK](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/master/third_party/lwip/FILES) (thanks to Jack Creasey for this!)

In the case of installing the Arduino core on an ESP8266, we can see that [the included libraries](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries) handle the networking, including Ethernet, DHCP, DNS, TCP/UDP, etc. - this allows you to customise the network stack if you wish.

Comment: The TCP/IP stack is fully documented by Expressif: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/master/third_party/lwip/FILES There is no need to cross to an Arduino core to get access to the stack code or API.

Comment: @JackCreasey So it is! My bad. Edited that in.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of ESP8266 implementations run the Expressif demo AT commands. You can look up info [here](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewforum.php?f=67&sid=2c83df268b2c1713293d1aa16679777a) on the Expressif SDK and all the documentation.

There is also an Open source implementation and GCC toolchain that works well [here](https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki).